# certificate KeyUsage and Cipher encryption mode

Tags: certificate, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt outgoing SOAP header, using cxf and sprint. As a result of my configutaion with spring I end up using outInterceptor for my client:

'

```
 <bean id="encryptOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">

  <constructor-arg>
     <map>
        <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp Encrypt" />
        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="passwordCallback" />
        <entry key="user" value="mykey" />
        <entry key="encryptionPropFile" value="keystore.properties" />

     </map>
  </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

`

and as a result of this it ends up calling

```
`org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.prepareInternal()`
```

method, I stepped through debugger to its source:

```
try {
        **cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, remoteCert);**
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new WSSecurityException(
            WSSecurityException.FAILED_ENCRYPTION, null, null, e
        );
    }
```

And at that point it throws: **"Invalid Key Usage"** exception.

I ended up writing a test java class, where I'm reading the certificate manually, then trying to initialize Cipher with **Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE** parameter,
and I ended up getting the same exception.here is specific snippet:

```
        InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("our_cert.cer");
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert =(X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        inStream.close();

        // Read the public key from certificate file
        RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();
        cipher.init(Cipher. ENCRYPT_MODE, certif);  // it breaks at this point
```

I replaced last line with

```
cipher.init(Cipher. PRIVATE_KEY, certif);
```

and it passed fine.

I don't think that's the right key usage though and I think that **ENCRYPT_MODE** should also work.

From looking at certificate keyusage section I noticed that it has key usage defined as:

```
ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]
```

and there are no other critical sections in it.

from the way it acts it appears that **Cipher.init(..)** works only for **DigitalSignature** (i.e. **Cipher. PRIVATE_KEY**) but not for  **Key_Encipherment** (i.e. **Cipher. ENCRYPT_MODE**).

So my question is, could it be possible that **KeyUsage** is not defined correctly for that certificate. 
I'm not cryptography expert, but some message board I was reading suggested that if keyUsage is critical, it might need to use
**DATA_ENCIPHERMENT** as well…

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Spelunking through the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.java.html), there are two conditions that throw that exception, one of which is a never-happen error, and the other is a check to see that the certificate in question supports the operation in question.

```
if (critSet != null && !critSet.isEmpty()
    && critSet.contains(KEY_USAGE_EXTENSION_OID)) {
  boolean[] keyUsageInfo = cert.getKeyUsage();
  // keyUsageInfo[2] is for keyEncipherment;
  // keyUsageInfo[3] is for dataEncipherment.
  if ((keyUsageInfo != null) &&
      (((opmode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) &&
      (keyUsageInfo.length > 3) &&
      (keyUsageInfo[3] == false)) ||
      ((opmode == Cipher.WRAP_MODE) &&
      (keyUsageInfo.length > 2) &&
      (keyUsageInfo[2] == false)))) {
      throw new InvalidKeyException("Wrong key usage");
    }
}
```

This suggests you're using a certificate that isn't valid for encryption. Perhaps you tried to use a public key cert for encryption?

It looks like the code doesn't check for opmode's that are always invalid like PRIVATE_KEY, just ones that are sometimes invalid like ENCRYPT_MODE, which is probably why it's fine with your test code.

Comment: Yes, by debugging Cipher.init() I did see that first condition is being met, i.e.:
 `(keyUsageInfo != null) &&
      (((opmode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) &&
      (keyUsageInfo.length > 3) &&
      (keyUsageInfo[3] == false)`

Keyusage in the certificate is supposed to support encryption, since it has this section:
`ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]`

or am I misreading it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe you're looking for "Data encipherment" rather than "Key encipherment." I imagine that would be Cipher.WRAP_MODE.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this recently. You can encrypt using a public key cert, provided it is created correctly. The cert should have the Key Usage Object ID (ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true), set to 'b0'(10110000) basically the Data Encipherment bit enabled. Otherwise you will run into the Wrong Key usage error. Any CA issued cert will have the Key Usage criticality turned to true. Self signed certs (like in dev/sandbox environments) will not have that criticality set to true, so those will work, provided of course you are set to trust them.
I tried using a public key cert from the server and was struggling with this error. Then our IT department got back with the right public key cert meant for Data Encipherment and it started working for me.